# Left Join a comparando dos campos en misma tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Tengo dos tabas, una de usuarios y otra de sesiones (campos de referencia):

```
Usuarios               Sesiones
--------               --------
| Id | Usuario |       | Id | Dominio_usuario | Usuario | Fecha_ingreso | Nombre  |
|----|---------|       |----|-----------------|---------|---------------|---------|
| 1  | C5725   |       | 1  | C5725           |         | 2020/12/18    | Ariel   |
| 2  | C5728   |       | 2  |                 | C5728   | 2020/12/18    | Juan    |
| 3  | C5729   |       | 3  | C5729           |         | 2020/12/18    | Roberto |
```

El asunto es que debo hacer un cruce entre estas tablas, para sacar la informacion completa por usuario, pero como se daran cuenta, en la tabla Sesiones, el nombre del usuario puede estar tanto en el campo Dominio_usuario o Usuario (Esto porque la aplicacion puede iniciarse tanto con nombre de usuario y contraseña o directamente desde el dominio de Windows) y el drama, es que no me resulta el left join que estoy haciendo:

De esta forma, los datos obtenidos se duplican:

```
SELECT *
FROM sesiones as t1
LEFT JOIN usuarios as t2
    ON (t1.Usuario = t2.Usuario or t1.Dominio_usuario = t2.Usuario)
```

De esta forma, obtengo la cantidad de registros correspondientes, pero pierdo datos a desplegar, como por ejemplo, el nombre real del usuario.

```
SELECT *
FROM sesiones as t1
LEFT JOIN usuarios as t2
   ON (t1.Usuario = t2.Usuario and t1.Dominio_usuario = t2.Usuario)
```

Hay alguna forma en la cual pueda hacer la comparacion de forma correcta u otro metodo?

Comment: tus querys son iguales.. podes mostrar el resultado de cada uno de ellos?

Comment: Disculpa, ahi edite la publicacion.

Comment: lla unica forma que veo que se te dupliquen los datos, es que en la tabla sesiones el usuario este mas de una vez.. es asi?

Comment: @gbianchi también puede pasar si dominio_usuario y usuario tienen diferentes valores a la vez

Comment: @Lamak algo que seria raro por lo que explica el usuario.. pero para mi, faltan datos.. con el or, deberia funcionar...

Comment: @gbianchi según leo, puede estar en cualquiera de las dos columnas, con lo que no veo que haya dicho que no puede estar en ambas. Si es así, con el `or` se duplicarían

Comment: ah si, @Lamak estamos hablando de lo mismo... por eso pregunte si la tabla sesiones no tenia mas datos ;) igual se le van a duplicar aunque el dato este en la misma columna mas de una vez...

Comment: Ese es el detalle, en la tabla sesiones, hay datos, o en el campo Usuario, o en el campo Dominio_usuario, o en ambos, por ello si ocupo `OR`, los datos se van a duplcar, por ello estoy buscando una forma en la cual pueda obtener la informacion que necesito, sin que se dupliquen los datos.

Comment: Agrega doble left join, a la misma tabla, una con la validación por usuario y la otra con dominio_usuario, y en tu consulta validas si el primero es nulo, entonces tomas el segundo

Comment: prueba utilizando union all para dominio_usuario y dominio

Comment: Gracias @Eduardo, gracias a tu consejo, logre crear la query que buscaba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias al comentario de Eduardo Jaramillo pude lograr la query que buscaba:

```
SELECT t1.Id, t2.Usuario, t1.Dominio_usuario, t1.Nombre, t1.Fecha_ingreso
FROM sesion as t1
LEFT JOIN usuario as t2
    ON t1.Dominio_usuario = t2.Usuario and t1.Dominio_usuario <> ''
LEFT JOIN de_usuario as t3
    ON t1.Usuario = t3.Usuario and t1.Usuario <> ''
ORDER BY t1.Id
```

Ojala les sirva tambien.